# building Debian package fails at dh_auto_install stage

Tags: debian, package-management

I'm trying to build a very simple debian package. I have two files, `main_file` and `functions`, they are both shell scripts, `functions` is sourced by `main_file`. There are no dependencies on any external packages, the code simply uses `echo`.

I have a `Makefile` that looks like this:

```
install:
    cp main_file $(DESTDIR)/usr/bin/main_file
    cp functions $(DESTDIR)/usr/bin/functions
```

I also have a control file in the debian directory, that looks like this:

```
Source: ad
Section: unknown
Priority: extra
Maintainer: James Kelly <james.kelly@email.com>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 7)
Standards-Version: 3.8.3
Homepage: <insert the upstream URL, if relevant>
Package: ad
Architecture: any
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
Description: Just messing around
 Playing with debian packages
```

I have a tar.gz file in the directory above the one which contains the code and debian folder containing the code and the `Makefile`.

If I run `$ dpkg-depcheck -d ./configure` I get an error:

```
strace: ./configure: command not found
Running strace failed (command line:
strace -e trace=open,execve -f -q -o /tmp/depchwOSqtO ./configure
```

I didn't think that would matter as there are no dependencies, then if I run `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot` I get an error:

```
dh_auto_clean
dh_auto_clean: failed to write to debian/ad.debhelper.log: Permission denied
END failed--call queue aborted.
make: *** [clean] Error 13
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2
```

Finally if I run `sudo dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot` the process gets further but then gives me an error:

```
dh_auto_install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/james/Dummy_Debian/ad-1.0'
cp main_file /home/james/Dummy_Debian/ad-1.0/debian/ad/usr/bin/main_file
cp: cannot create regular file `/home/james/Dummy_Debian/ad-1.0/debian/ad/usr/bin/main_file': No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/james/Dummy_Debian/ad-1.0'
dh_auto_install: make -j1 install DESTDIR=/home/james/Dummy_Debian/ad-1.0/debian/ad returned exit code 2
make: *** [binary] Error 29
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
```

I've been banging my head against this all day and I feel that it's probably something simple that I'm doing wrong, if anyone could give me some help I'd be eternally grateful!

EDIT:

My rules file is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# -*- makefile -*-
# Sample debian/rules that uses debhelper.
# This file was originally written by Joey Hess and Craig Small.
# As a special exception, when this file is copied by dh-make into a
# dh-make output file, you may use that output file without restriction.
# This special exception was added by Craig Small in version 0.37 of dh-make.

# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
#export DH_VERBOSE=1

%:
    dh  $@
```

[and a link to a zip file containing my sample code.](http://www.kells1986.com/deb/my_debian_stuff.zip)

Comment: My 1st bet would be checking /home/james/Dummy_Debian/ad-1.0/debian/ad/usr/bin/ for permissions issuesm as well as checking if the path exists.

Comment: The path doesn't exist, but shouldn't `dpkg-buildpackage` make this for me or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I suggest uploading your code, including the Debian packaging, somewhere public - e.g. Bitbucket or Github, and provide a link to it in your question. Then it may be possible for someone to figure out what your problem is. From your description it sounds like you are making some elementary packaging mistake(s), but there is nothing to be gained in trying to guess what.

Comment: Post your `debian/rules` file. You may need to register the directories like `usr/bin` in `debian/dirs`, depending on which dh tools you're using. `debian/ad.debhelper.log: Permission denied` is weird: what are the permissions on the `debian` directory?

Comment: +1 for the `debian/dirs` hint. Your `install` target is broken, though; it should create the directory (with correct permissions!) if it is missing.

Answer (score 2):

debhelper(7) tries to use broken `Makefile` to build (`dh_auto_build`) and install (`dh_auto_install`) files so either `Makefile` has to be fixed or we can ignore it by adding overrides to `debian/rules`:

```
override_dh_auto_build override_dh_auto_install:  
        @
```

and making `debian/install` file with following contents:

```
main_file  /usr/bin
functions  /usr/bin
```

Read more about Debian packaging in

- https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging
- https://wiki.debian.org/IntroDebianPackaging
- https://wiki.debian.org/PackagingTutorial
- http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/packaging-tutorial/packaging-tutorial.en.pdf